# Анимация формы текста, снаружи анимации формы

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

Я пытаюсь добиться следующей анимации  абзаца текста :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Цель состоит в том, чтобы анимировать границы текста в соответствии с изменяемой формой слева.
Этот код, который я пробовал, но я не могу понять `transition` по форме текста:

```css
.mainDiv {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #e3f5f1;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.textElement {
  width: 395px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="textElement">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus Page Maker including versions of Lorem Ipsum, and more recently with desktop publishing software.
  </div>
</div>
```

У меня недостаточно знаний о `transitions` и анимации `CSS`, поэтому я надеюсь получить некоторую помощь.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/36496568/7394871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ещё один пример с совершенно другой техникой.

Каждая строчка текста сдвигается на определенное расстояние, создавая иллюзию выдвигания фигуры слева.

```css
.text {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.shape {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 1.25em;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.text:hover .shape {
  position: static;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <div class="shape" style="width: 7em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 8em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 9em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 10em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 11em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 12em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width:11em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 10em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 9em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 8em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 7em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 4em"></div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis repellendus quaerat maiores ex officia molestiae, recusandae nostrum. Molestiae reiciendis non at eius adipisci ipsam facilis! Laudantium voluptatibus assumenda exercitationem veritatis
  explicabo maxime saepe, voluptatum? Officia, sequi vero nihil vitae. Blanditiis distinctio aspernatur voluptatem assumenda porro, dolores quibusdam ullam reiciendis cumque repellendus perspiciatis dolore, odio illum! Itaque aliquid sapiente blanditiis
  reprehenderit nam ullam necessitatibus voluptatibus! Iusto dignissimos corporis porro minima esse quas nemo, asperiores repellat dolorum, dolore nisi impedit sequi

</div>
```

Comment: интересная мысль, интересный эффект. То есть каждая строчка текста сдвигается на определенное расстояние при наведении. В целом получается похожий эффект, как в ответе автора Enso/ Вот бы ещё покрасить пустое пространство на площади сдвига и сделать эффект более плавным.

Comment: да я согласен @Alexandr_TT это просто для примера ... я когда то задавал этот вопрос на so и на ruSO и вот такой креативный ответ дали на so

Comment: доработать сможешь?

Comment: да нее.... возни много ... лень - для примера покатит а как рабочий нет ... самое лучшее у тебя но тоже ни везде сработает ...для примера в Лисе ...

Comment: Да, про это в заголовке написано, что только в браузерах семейства `webkit`

Comment: мой пример будет везде работать ... даже в IE5 но допиливать лень если честно

Comment: отдал решение вам. Немного подредактировал ваш топик. Всё же надеюсь, что не забудете этот ответ и когда появится время и желание добавите цвет. Будет смотреться совсем по другому.

Comment: там же цвет добавлен .. просто я лично люблю цвета которые не бросаются в глаза

Comment: я имел ввиду не background целиком, а только освобождающуюся площадь после сдвига

Comment: там не возможно это сделать ... позиционирование не анимируется ... для этого нужен js а я в нём не силён

Answer (score 4):

> **Disclaimer**: Свойство формы  [`shape-outside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside) не должно использоваться в текущих проектах. Они могут подвергаться
>   нежелательному поведению.

Этот вид макета может быть достигнут с помощью анимации свойств `shape-outside` и `clip-path`. Оба свойства могут быть `transitioned` для создания анимации.

Недостатком является то, что оба свойства имеют очень низкую поддержку браузеров, и сегодня эта анимация будет работать только в браузерах `webkit`, так как `Firefox` и `IE / Edge` не поддерживают свойство `shape-outside` или свойство `clip-path` с значением `polygon()`.

Ниже пример толко для браузеров **`webkit`** : `Chrome`, `Opera`, `Yandex`

```css
.mainDiv{
  width:600px;
  margin:0px auto;
  border:solid 1px #000;
  padding:10px;
  min-height:200px;
}
.element{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:#e3f5f1;
  float:left;
  margin-right:5px;
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
          shape-outside: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path:polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
          clip-path:polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  transition: clip-path 1s, shape-outside 1s;
  transition: -webkit-clip-path 1s, shape-outside 1s;
}
.element:hover{
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 0 100%);
          shape-outside: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 0 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path:polygon(0% 0%, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 0 100%);
          clip-path:polygon(0% 0%, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 0 100%);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="element"></div>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus Page Maker including versions of Lorem Ipsum, and more recently with desktop publishing software.
</div>
```

Источник: [Text shape animation, animating shape-outside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36497054/7394871) @web-tiki